# How to get who sent the intent to the service?

Tags: android, binding, android-intent, android-service

If my service got an intent of starting, binding or unbinding it, I would like to know the name of the class that has done it.

How do I fetch which class has sent the intent that the service got via these methods?

Is it even possible? If so, how?  If not, why, and how can I overcome it in case I want to monitor who is bound to the service and when it unbinds from the service?

I've tried multiple methods of the Intent class, but none seem to be able to query this data.

Comment: Are these intents always going to be your own or could they belong to other party applications

Comment: @Orlymee : maybe . i prefer having a more general solution .

Comment: @Future2020 : what about unbind? this cannot have an extra. should i just change the interface between the service and and others , to include something like bind and unbind?

Comment: @Tushar Dhoot i can't do it here , since they didn't put the answers in , well , an answer . they've written in in comments.

Answer (score -2):

```
//You can put activity name in the intent object like this
Intent intent=new Intent(this,myservice.class);
intent.putExtra("activity_name","MainActivity");
startService(intent);


//While in service you get this values by writing
Intent intent=getIntent();
String name=intent.getStringExtra("activity_name");
//.....
```

Comment: what about unbinding ? will it still work there? also ,what about activities from other apps ?